# How to Copy a Variable Range of Rows and Columns from one Workbook to Another?

Tags: excel, vba, loops, copy-paste

I'm using a Master excel file to pull data in from outside workbooks. Currently, my macro accounts for a variable range of rows but I cannot figure out how to also account for a variable range of columns.

The code below requires that I enter a range of cells that I would like to copy. Ideally, I would like to remove J so that I am not limited to an outside column but I haven't been able to figure that out through research. To make matters more complicated I have formulas in columns K and L that reference the values in Column A but that is a separate issue isn't urgent.

```
Sub Copy_Raw_Data()

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False

  Dim CopySheet As Worksheet
  Dim pasteSheet As Worksheet

  Set CopySheet = Worksheets("Raw Data Sheet1")
  Set pasteSheet = Worksheets("Master Sheet")

  Workbooks.Open ("S:\Raw Data.xlsx")

  With Sheets("Raw Data Sheet1").Range("A2:J" & Cells(Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Row).Copy

  Workbooks("Master.xlsm").Activate

  pasteSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
  Application.CutCopyMode = False
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True

  End With

  Workbooks("Raw Data.xlsx").Save
  Workbooks("Raw Data.xlsx").Close

  Worksheets("Master Sheet").Select

End Sub
```

I expect the copy to transfer a variable range of rows and columns from the 'Raw Data' workbook to the 'Master' workbook. Taking it one step further I would like my formulas in the last two columns to shift with the new data.

Comment: Have you tried adjusting your references for ranges? 
 E.g., *Range("A2:B3")* is not as easy to utilize variables as *Range(Cells(2,1),Cells(3,"B")* (yes, i chose to show 1 for A and B as "B", which should let one know that either numeric or alpha variables can be used).

Answer (score 0):

Example of comment:

```
dim sr as long, er as long, sc as long, ec as long
sr = 2 'starting row
er = cells(rows.count,1).end(xlup).row 'end row
sc = 1 'starting column ("A")
ec = cells(1, rows.count).end(xltoleft).column 'end column
'utilize above variables
Range(Cells(sr,sc),Cells(er,ec)).Value = ""
```